# how to use spring boot actuator on a docker swarm or docker stack deployment

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-swarm, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-docker-plugin

I am exploring spring boot on docker. I have a spring boot application with actuator enabled to see the metrics. I am deploying the app to a docker container either as a stack deployment or swarm, i have 3 replicas of the spring boot app and they are in a ingress network.

If i access the spring actuator metrics then it's giving the metrics of one among the 3 servers. is there a way to get the metrics of each docker container or what is the best/right approach to monitor container and get the actuator metrics or what tools/ framework is used to monitor the health and metrics of spring boot app on docker.

Comment: Interesting question, what have you decided for? You should probably consider https://prometheus.io.